# JXLS Multiple sheets fail when using different sized lists newt to eachother

Tags: jxls

I'm using nearly same code with the Multiple sheets demo, only difference is I have 4 different lists on a sheet. (template4)

- If I run this example just for 1 sheet, that works perfect.
- If I remove the SUM formulas, it works.
- If I modify the template and remove the lists on the same row, It works, (template5)
- If I use same sized lists for each part, it works.

[here's the templates](http://www.globalbilisim.com/download/file_templates.zip)

here's the code:

```
public void excelExport() throws IOException {
    LogManager.getLogger("org.jxls.area.XlsArea").setLevel(Level.ERROR);
    try (FileOutputStream os = new FileOutputStream("c:/Temp/xxx.xls")) {
        try (InputStream is =new FileInputStream("C:\\Works\\workspace-intellij\\nostro-vaadin\\src\\main\\resources\\file_templates\\report5_template.xls")) {
            Transformer transformer = TransformerFactory.createTransformer(is, os);
            XlsArea xlsArea = new XlsArea("template!A1:G20", transformer);

            XlsArea corrsArea = new XlsArea("template!A2:G19", transformer);
            EachCommand corrsEach = new EachCommand("val", "data", corrsArea, new ExcelCellRefGenerator());

            XlsArea bookDebitArea = new XlsArea("template!A8:C8", transformer);
            Command bookDebitEach = new EachCommand("bookDebit", "val.dbooks", bookDebitArea);
            corrsArea.addCommand(new AreaRef("template!A8:C8"), bookDebitEach);

            XlsArea bookCreditArea = new XlsArea("template!E8:G8", transformer);
            Command bookCreditEach = new EachCommand("bookCredit", "val.cbooks", bookCreditArea);
            corrsArea.addCommand(new AreaRef("template!E8:G8"), bookCreditEach);

            XlsArea statDebitArea = new XlsArea("template!A12:C12", transformer);
            Command statDebitEach = new EachCommand("statDebit", "val.dstmts", statDebitArea);
            corrsArea.addCommand(new AreaRef("template!A12:C12"), statDebitEach);

            XlsArea statCreditArea = new XlsArea("template!E12:G12", transformer);
            Command statCreditEach = new EachCommand("statCredit", "val.cstmts", statCreditArea);
            corrsArea.addCommand(new AreaRef("template!E12:G12"), statCreditEach);

            xlsArea.addCommand(corrsArea.getAreaRef(), corrsEach);

            Context context = new Context();
            context.putVar("data", getList(10, 50));
            xlsArea.applyAt(new CellRef("Sheet!A1"), context);
            xlsArea.processFormulas();
            transformer.write();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            log.error("", e);
        }
    }
}

public List<ExcelReportSheet> getList(int bank, int trans) {
    List<ExcelReportSheet> sheets = new ArrayList<>();
    for (int i = 0; i < bank; i++) {
        NsCorrespondents corr = new NsCorrespondents();
        corr.setBankcode(i + "bank");
        corr.setBankname(i + "bankname");
        corr.setBic(i + "bankbic");
        corr.setShdBbalance(new BigDecimal("10000"));
        corr.setShdSbalance(new BigDecimal("20000"));
        ExcelReportSheet reportSheet = new ExcelReportSheet(corr);
        Random random = new Random();
        for (int j = 0; j < random.nextInt(trans); j++) {
            reportSheet.getCbooks().add(ExcelReportSheet.ExcelReportTran.of(Date.valueOf(LocalDate.now()), j + "-" + i + "cbref", new BigDecimal(random.nextInt(trans))));
        }
        for (int j = 0; j < random.nextInt(trans); j++) {
            reportSheet.getDbooks().add(ExcelReportSheet.ExcelReportTran.of(Date.valueOf(LocalDate.now()), j + "-" + i + "cbref", new BigDecimal(random.nextInt(trans))));
        }
        for (int j = 0; j < random.nextInt(trans); j++) {
            reportSheet.getCstmts().add(ExcelReportSheet.ExcelReportTran.of(Date.valueOf(LocalDate.now()), j + "-" + i + "cbref", new BigDecimal(random.nextInt(trans))));
        }
        for (int j = 0; j < random.nextInt(trans); j++) {
            reportSheet.getDstmts().add(ExcelReportSheet.ExcelReportTran.of(Date.valueOf(LocalDate.now()), j + "-" + i + "cbref", new BigDecimal(random.nextInt(trans))));
        }

        sheets.add(reportSheet);
    }
    return sheets;
}
```

This is the error I'm getting. I believe it mixes the SUM formulas from different sheets.

Any help would be appreciated.

`14:57:20.455 [main] ERROR o.jxls.transform.poi.PoiTransformer - Failed to set formula = SUM(C19,C20,Sheet1!C20,Sheet1!C21,Sheet1!C22,Sheet1!C23,Sheet1!C24,Sheet1!C25,Sheet1!C26,Sheet1!C27,Sheet1!C28,Sheet1!C29,Sheet1!C30,Sheet1!C31,Sheet1!C32,Sheet3!C21,Sheet3!C22,Sheet3!C23,Sheet3!C24,Sheet3!C25,Sheet4!C18,Sheet4!C19,Sheet4!C20,Sheet4!C21,Sheet4!C22,Sheet4!C23,Sheet4!C24,Sheet5!C23,Sheet5!C24,Sheet5!C25,Sheet5!C26,Sheet5!C27,Sheet5!C28,Sheet5!C29,Sheet5!C30,Sheet6!C19,Sheet6!C20,Sheet6!C21,Sheet6!C22,Sheet6!C23,Sheet6!C24,Sheet6!C25,Sheet6!C26,Sheet6!C27,Sheet6!C28,Sheet7!C16,Sheet7!C17,Sheet7!C18,Sheet7!C19,Sheet7!C20,Sheet7!C21,Sheet7!C22,Sheet7!C23,Sheet7!C24,Sheet7!C25,Sheet7!C26,Sheet7!C27,Sheet8!C12,Sheet8!C13,Sheet9!C27,Sheet9!C28,Sheet9!C29,Sheet9!C30,Sheet9!C31,Sheet9!C32,Sheet9!C33,Sheet9!C34,Sheet9!C35,Sheet9!C36,Sheet9!C37,Sheet9!C38,Sheet9!C39,Sheet9!C40) into cell = Sheet0!C16`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you have a complex template or a transformation with multiple lists the default Jxls formula processor (named *FastFormulaProcessor*) may not evaluate the formulas correctly.

In this case you should use *StandardFormulaProcessor()* which is slower but works reliably in all cases. You can configure the formula processor to use by adding the following code somewhere before *processFormulas()* method

```
xlsArea.setFormulaProcessor(new StandardFormulaProcessor());
```